# Пересечение множеств полученных из текстовых файлов (с одинаковым содержанием) размещенных в указанном каталоге

Tags: python, множества

Помогите пожалуйста!
Задача: считать содержимое указанного каталога (конкретно файлы.txt), записать содержимое каждого файла в отдельную переменную (преобразовать в множество),сравнить полученные множества между собой на предмет повторяющихся значений, вывести полученные значения в отдельный файл.
Реализовано: открываю указанный пользователем (произвольный) каталог, и записываю содержимое файлов  в ОДНУ переменную (в виде множеств)....
Проблема: как записать содержимое файлов из директории в РАЗНЫЕ переменные для последующего сравнения?
Вот пример кода:

```
import os
name_catalog = (input('Имя входного каталога:'))
path = (os.listdir(name_catalog))
for i in path:
    with open(name_catalog + '\\' + i, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for i in f:
            a = set(f.read().split())
```

получил 2 списка в переменной 'a':

```
{'илья', 'петя', 'динара', 'вася'}
{'валера', 'андрей', 'пол', 'аня', 'саша', 'петя', 'дима'}
```

или если можно как то сравнить эти множества в рамках ОДНОЙ переменно?

Comment: Во первых, это не списки, во вторых, в таком виде это не может быть в одной переменной. Что именно в а? Вообще, там получаются данные из последнего прочитанного файла.

Comment: Да, это вроде как множества (содержимое 2 файлов которые лежат в каталоге)                                    функция print(a) возвращает следующий результат:                    

{'динара', 'вася', 'петя', 'илья'}
<class 'set'>
{'саша', 'петя', 'андрей', 'пол', 'валера', 'аня', 'дима'}
<class 'set'>                                                                                                                                                  не совсем понимаю они записались в переменную а? циклом for (a = set(f.read().split())?

Comment: А что вы ожидаете увидеть на выходе? 'петя'?

Comment: Да верно 'петя'. На выходе должны быть одинаковые элементы множеств (потом я записываю их в файл)                                                                                                                                                                           С конкретными файлами проблем нет (если их прописать в коде D:\ Список 1) считываю и сохраняю в переменную в виде множества, потом сравниваю Но если брать из произвольной директории начинаются проблемы, как считать файлы в разные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

в РАЗНЫЕ переменные, например в список

```
path = (os.listdir(name_catalog))
a = []
for i in path:
    with open(name_catalog + '\\' + i, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        a.append(set(f.read().split()))
print(a)
[{'динара', 'петя', 'илья', 'вася'}, {'саша', 'дима', 'андрей', 'валера', 'пол', 'аня', 'петя'}]

z, *pt = a
for x in pt:
    z &= x

print(*z)

петя
```

Comment: Получилось. Все записал в один список:                                                                                                [['зина', 'илья', 'динара', 'вася', 'петя'], ['вася', 'петя', 'дима', 'андрей', 'саша', 'валера', 'аня', 'пол']]                  теперь пытаюсь сравнить элементы списка (на предмет повторений), но из-за того что эти элементы тоже списки (получается 2 подсписка) на выходе получаю - [],"ноль".